# forcing gulp to use a different hostname

Tags: dns, gulp

I need "gulp serve" to serve my application on a hostname that I added in my hosts file and not localhost. I'm doing this for cookie reasons since I'm adding domain key everytime I add a cookie.

For example
127.0.0.1  app1.example.org

When I start "gulp serve", it would trigger the web browser and put http://app1.example.org:3000 or whatever tcp port it is running.

Comment: `gulp serve` can be anything. Please tell us your gulp plugins and setup that you use.

Comment: I'm using the one that yeoman angular-foundation is using. Right now, I see these in my gulpfile.js require('gulp'); require('gulp-util'); require('wrench');

Comment: I just run gulp serve so my angular application will start

Comment: maybe it would help if you could copy'n'paste your Gulpfile, or point to the right yeoman generator on Github... still groping in the dark, because it could be anything

Comment: This is what I used - https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at the Gulpfile from your link (thanks btw, this was important) I now know that the server being used there is `browser-sync`. With `browser-sync` changing the hostname is really easy.

Go to your application and enter the `gulp` folder. There you should see a `_server.js` file. This is where the configurations of your server are stored. Find the line that says `browserSync.instance = browserSync.init({` and change it to the following:

```
browserSync.instance = browserSync.init({
    startPath: '/',
    server: server,
    browser: browser,
    host: 'app1.example.org',
    open: 'external'
});
```

If you then have the right line placed in our `/etc/hosts` file this should open correctly. For more options see: http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/

Comment: You are amazing! You are the best ddprrt! It worked! I really thank you for spending the time working on this!!! :D Thank you so much!!!

Comment: For other lurkers who are very curious why I'm doing this. It's because I have a code in my AngularJS application that stores cookie and the way I store cookie also saves the domain. I added the domain option. So if I'm running it on localhost:3000 and I'm adding a cookie with the domain option of example.org, you will notice that the cookie doesn't get added. I always have to manually type app.example.org before the cookie starts working.

Comment: [continuation] If let's say after few days I don't work on my app and when I get back to it, I start it with localhost:3000, I'll wonder why my app is behaving in a weird way. I'll start troubleshooting and few minutes later, I'll remember that I have to load app.example.org instead. So with the solution that ddprrt showed above, I won't have to worry about remembering the loaded fqdn :)